# mu4e takes "seen" flag away from email after replying to it

Tags: mu4e

Problem:

When responding to an email, mu4e appears to remove the "seen" property from the email. Before responding, the email's filename in the Maildir ends with "S" (indicating that the email has been seen), and after responding, the email ends with "R" instead. As a result mu4e (wrongly) gives that email an "unread" flag.

Excpected behaviour:

After responding to an email that I have seen, I expect the filename of the email in the maildir to end with "RS" (read and seen).

- mu version 1.11.3
- Spacemacs v.0.999.0

Comment: I removed tag `Spacemacs`. If there's something relevant about Spacemacs in your question then please make that explicit in the question (and add the tag back). Thx.

Comment: I understand. Thanks.